# Make EditText not lose focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, imagebutton, long-press

I have an EditText and an ImageButton (in different ViewGroups) on a single page.

If the EditText is focused, I dont want to unfocus the EditText when I click on the ImageButton.

I tried setting imageButton.setFocusable(false);
It didn't work.
If I long-press on the imageButton the EditText does not lose focus.

EDIT:
I don't want the edittext to lose the focus, not even for some milisecs.
I have a layout that is depending on the "isFocused" property on the EditText.

Comment: Provide some code snippets

Comment: I cannot, I'm actually using xamarin.android + xamarin.forms. but i cant get to intercept the touch event, so it does not focus the button

Answer (score 0):

If you try this?

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.requestFocus();
        }
});
```

Comment: sadly, this doesnt work since the edittext still loses the focus for a short duration of time. "isFocused" shouldnt change at all when i press the imageButton

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: theres already an answer that suggests the "requestFocus()" call on the edittext. it doesnt help me tho, i explained the case in the other comment

Comment: Did you try the code I have posted ? If no then try it please.